# Inconsistent python mmap behaviour with /dev/mem

Tags: python, linux, mmap

I've been working on a project in PHP which requires mmap'ing `/dev/mem` to gain access to the hardware peripheral registers.  As there's no native mmap, the simplest way I could think of to achieve this was to construct a python subprocess, which communicated with the PHP app via `stdin/stdout`.

I have run into a strange issue which only occurs while reading addresses, not writing them.  The subprocess functions correctly (for reading) with the following:

```
mem.write(sys.stdin.read(length))
```

So, I expected that I could conversely write memory segments back to the parent using the following:

```
sys.stdout.write(mem.read(length))
```

If I mmap a standard file, both commands work as expected (irrelevant of the length of read/write).  If I map the `/dev/mem` "file," I get nonsense back during the read.  It's worth noting that the area I'm mapping is outside the physical memory address space and is used to access the peripheral registers.

The work-around I have in place is the following:

```
for x in range(0, length / 4):
    sys.stdout.write(str(struct.pack('L', struct.unpack_from('L', mem, mem.tell())[0])))
    mem.seek(4, os.SEEK_CUR)
```

This makes the reads behave as expected.

What I can't understand is why reading from the address using `unpack_from` should see anything different to reading it directly.  The same (non-working) thing occurs if I try to just assign a read to a variable.

In case additional context is helpful, I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi/Debian 8. The file that contains the above issue is [here](https://github.com/calcinai/php-mmap/blob/master/subprocess/mmap-proxy.py#L27).  The project that uses it is [here](https://github.com/calcinai/phpi).